# How to convert complex date string into datetime java

Tags: java, datetime, formatting

I have the following string that I need put into a date time

Sat, 21-May-2011 21:31:35 GMT

So far I'm doing the following but I'm not sure of the valid format to get this parsed. Any help would be appreciated!

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = df.parse("Sat, 21-May-2011 21:31:35 GMT");
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you expect that simple 'no time' format to parse a string with a timestamp on the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See documentation for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for format guidence
You should have something like this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```